# ClipCursor not working for touch based experience

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application, where I need to allow user to rearrange objects by drag-drop. It is basically dragging objects within a canvas area and moving them to another area of the canvas. The mouse cursor would change to a drag cursor while dragging is happening.

The requirement is like the mouse pointer cannot leave the canvas area while the dragging is in progress. For that I am using the Win32 ClipCursor api to restrict the cursor to a certain boundary of the screen.

This is working fine when mouse is used. However, if touch is used, i.e. if the pointer is moved through touch, it is possible to take the cursor out of the bounding rectangle. Can anyone please help to understand why it is happening? I am handling the PreviewMouseMove and MouseLeftButtonUp events for starting and ending the drag. Do I need to handle the Touch and the Stylus events as well?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't necessarily try to limit the movement of mouse pointer itself but the movement of the object to be dragged inside Canvas. If the pointer goes out of Canvas, just wait for returning of the pointer and then resume the movement of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but here the 'object' is the (customized) cursor itself, and I do not see any way to intercept the message before the cursor changes position. I used Win32 api SetCursorPos to change the cursor position somewhere within the canvas, but that causes a nasty flicker.